# What is the most efficient method to plot large Adjacency Matrices (not Graphs)?

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, lattice, network-analysis

I am searching an efficient way to plot large Adjacency Matrices (>1M nodes) in R.
The aim is not to plot them as a Network Graph but to plot the Adjacency Matrix itself.

This is quite a common visualization in the field of network analysis and especially community detection but I can't seem to find a way to achieve such a plot in R. The closest that I can find is the function `levelplot()` from lattice but it doesn't seem to be able to handle matrices of this size.

Below is an example of the desired result from a paper by [Reichardt & Bornholdt](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-92267-4_7).
Adjacency matrices can be downloaded from the [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first bet was to look at the `image` method from the Matrix package. An example could be something like:

```r
#####
# simulate a random matrix
n <- 1000000L # number of nodes
set.seed(1)
rng_i <- sample.int(n, size = 100L * n, replace = TRUE)
rng_j <- sample.int(n, size = 100L * n, replace = TRUE)
i <- c(1:n, rng_i, rng_j)
j <- c(1:n, rng_j, rng_i)
x <- runif(n * 100L)
x <- c(rep(1, n), x, x)

keep <- j <= i & c(rep(TRUE, n), tail(i, -n) != tail(j, -n))
j <- j[keep]
i <- i[keep]
x <- x[keep]

# use the image method from Matrix
library(Matrix)
mat <- sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = x, symmetric = TRUE)
image(mat)
```

This takes a while but turns out to be based on `levelplot` from `lattice`. The output is a big blank plot.

Thinking a bit about, if you have say a 102 x 102 mm picture (~ 4 x 4 inch) and a 1m x 1m matrix, then there is ~ .0001 x .0001 mm per entry of the matrix if we disregard the axis etc. Not knowing much about human perception or images, I am guessing that you would need a very large number of pixels per inch in order to plot these and I am not sure if this will be perceivable unless there are larger clusters of adjacent non-zero entries.

On the other hand, if you change `n <- 10000L` then you get:

[image]

fairly fast. The above also gives an indication as to how hard it will be perceive boxes that are 1/100 x 1/100 smaller. I am guessing one would have to look for the number of adjacent non-zero nodes in a larger neighborhood but I am not aware of a package that will do that.

Comment: You're the best!
This is exactly the kind of function I was searching. However, at first I had problems when ordering the rows & columns by communities because apparently the community detection algorithm I used sorted the nodes in each community by its centrality. So to achieve the desired result I needed to randomize the rows & columns before sorting by community.

Comment: Excellent! I am happy to help.